# Subset data.table by condition but retain all rows belonging to group

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I have data that looks like this:

```
require("data.table")
dt1 <- data.table(
  code=c("A001", "A001","A001","A002","A002","A002","A002","A003","A003"),
  value=c(40,38,55,10,12,16,18,77,87))
```

I would like to subset it so any group (`code`) that contains a value over or under a given number is retained. For example, if I wanted any group that contained a value over 50 then the result would look like this:

```
dt2 <- data.table(
  code=c("A001", "A001","A001","A003","A003"),
  value=c(40,38,55,77,87))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We create a condition with `any` after grouping by 'code' to subset the rows

```
dt1[, if(any(value > 50)) .SD,  code]
```

Or without the `if` condition

```
dt1[,  .SD[any(value > 50)],  code]
```

Or get the row indices (`.I`) and subset based on that

```
dt1[dt1[,  .I[any(value > 50)],  code]$V1]
```